# Network indicator panel not showing wired connection

Tags: networking

I am successfully connected to my router via ethernet cable, but that's what my indicator shows:

[image]

I also reinstalled the indicator and rebooted but nothing changed. I reinstalled using this:

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

Is this a bug, or I can somehow fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is by design. See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=708966 --- the developers decided that having an indicator for a fixed connection was not useful.

For what I deduced, the indicator is back in 3.12, but Ubuntu uses 3.10. (To be exact, 3.10.4).

Other interesting links are http://kasunc.blogspot.com.es/2013/12/workaround-for-wired-network-connection.html, and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=170967.

Comment: Interesting, but just a few weeks ago it was showing my wired connection with two arrows. Now if I remove the cable, nothing changes and I cannot see if I am disconnected or connected, so quite strange. Thanks anyways.