# Ethernet interface Ubuntu 14

Tags: ethernet

My ethernet interface is disabled on Ubuntu 14, I had no problem with Ubuntu 12.

Comment: Is it present but disabled or is there another issue? Please add your OS version, is it 14.04, 14.10...?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a case of http://askubuntu.com/questions/551763/network-indicator-panel-not-showing-wired-connection

Answer (score 0):

try this
'sudo ifdown -a'
'sudo ifup -a'